# Postgres version compatibility

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

I was using PostgresSQL version 9.6 with JDBC driver 9.4-1206-jdbc42 to connect to Java. I was using the `SimpleJDBCCall` of Springs to connect to the database.

However, after the upgrade of PostgreSQL to 10.5, we are unable to use the `SimpleJDBCCall` API. Any light on this issue will be of great help.

Comment: 9.4-1206-jdbc42  is quite old. Why are you using such an old driver version? It wasn't even the correct driver to be used with Postgres 9.6 even less so with Postgres 10

Comment: Please post relevant code, errors, etc (a [mcve]).

Answer (score 2):

You should never use a version of the JDBC driver that is older than the PostgreSQL server release.

The recommendation is to always use the latest driver version. A new driver will know how to talk to an old server, while an old driver might not know how to talk to a new server.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried changing it to the version 42.5.5  postgresSQL, instead of the version 9.4-1206-jdbc42 which is the latest version release. But of no use. the SimpleJDBCCall does not get executed with this.

Comment: Ok, then post some code, together with a detailed description of the misbehavior.